# Parsing date always returning 01 Jan 1970

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat, utc

I am getting datetime from server in UTC so I need to convert it in local time and need to store in db in long format.

But whenever I receive time, I parse it in `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"`and then convert it in to `long` and store it in table. but when i tried to fetch i am always getting `01 Jan 1970`.

Here is my code :

This is the format in which I am getting from server : `"tourCreationDateTime":"2020-03-04T07:12:52.215+0000"`.

```
// insert tour details
Tour tour = new Tour();
if (tourId > 0) {
     tour.setId(tourId);
}
tour.setStatus(Constants.TOUR_STATUS_OPEN);
tour.setTourNumber(tourResponseDetails.getTourId());
tour.setCreatedDateTime(DateUtils.getFormattedDate(tourResponseDetails.getTourCreationDateTime(), DateUtils.DATE_FORMAT_DB));
tourDao().insertTour(tour);
```

Here is my date format  :

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_DB = "yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
```

Here is `getFormattedDate` method :

```
 public static long getFormattedDate(String dateString, String format){
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(dateString)){
        return 0L;
    }

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateString);
        return date.getTime();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0L;
}
```

I don't what's going wrong. Any reference will be really good.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/): `return LocalDateTime.parse(dateString) .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .toInstant() .toEpochMilli();`. Or if the string is in UTC: `return LocalDateTime.parse(dateString) .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC) .toInstant() .toEpochMilli();`.

Comment: Had you debugger gone on holiday? :-) Voting to close as simple typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(dateString)){
    return 0L;
}
```

and 0L is 01 Jan 1970.
Mistake here - `if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(dateString))`.
are you sure that it should contain !//exclamation mark

Comment: silly mistake :-). And i am trying to find out the root cause from last 30 minute. Need to go home now :-)